# How long is canned ham good for left out of the fridge?

Tags: food-safety

My son was needing help with some food because he was laid off from work. So i told him i would leave him care package on the porch that consisted of an armour canned ham. It was late at night in October so it was cool out and i thought it would be ok, but had text me saying he wouldn't be able to come get it until the next day sometime, but i didn't see the message until around 11:15am. So by the time i got it and put it back in the fridge it was already starting to get a little warm. I went ahead and stuck it in the fridge immediately. I just need to know if it would be safe for him and his family to eat it. All opinions appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please see the duplicate target, and also our basic info on food safety under https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info. Basically, the only thing that matters here is if it is shelf-stable (that means, the ham can be stored at room temperature, and the original package was not opened) or not.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if it was shelf stable or marked “keep refrigerated”.

From [Arizona Cooperative Extension](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwjY5ZPEn-DlAhWPpZ4KHYzMDs8QFjABegQIDRAG&url=https%3A%2F%2Fextension.arizona.edu%2Fpubs%2Faz1089.pdf&usg=AOvVaw36aycYyJs_iYQDKCG7iWxA)

> Canned hams labeled “keep refrigerated” require refrigeration and, unopened, will keep 6 to 9 months in the refrigerator. Once canned hams are opened, keep them refrigerated and use within 3 to 5 days. Make sure the can isn’t showing any bulges, cracks, dents or rust, or leaking any liquid. A canned ham should not be frozen. Shelf-stable canned hams do not require refrigeration and may be stored in a cool, dry place for 2 to 5 years.

From [USDA](https://www.fsis.usda.gov/wps/portal/fsis/topics/food-safety-education/get-answers/food-safety-fact-sheets/meat-preparation/ham-and-food-safety/ct_index)

> Refrigerated - May be stored in the refrigerator for up to 6 to 9 months. Its weight can be up to 8% more than original uncured weight due to the uptake of water during curing. It need not be labeled "Added water" except for "In Natural Juices." Net Weight is the weight of the actual ham excluding the container. Processed at a cook time and temperature sufficient to kill infectious organisms (including trichinae); however, the ham is not sterilized so spoilage bacteria may grow eventually.

Comment: That seems to be another area where the US differs from everywhere else. I have never in my life seen a can that had to be refrigerated. That is truly bizarre.

Comment: @Tetsujin the idea of putting a ham in a can is truly bizarre to me ;)

Comment: Well, yes… it's revolting stuff ;) but once canned it should be like any other can… good until punctured.

Comment: @Tetsujin see last line in updated answer.

Comment: Yeah… still weird to a Brit. To me, canned is canned, no further intervention needed until opened.

Comment: The can says keep refrigerated.